# Webfacing and HATS IE 11 support

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11, app-certification-kit

Good day!
I would like to ask if Webfacing and HATS support Internet Explorer 11? I can't find IBM site that I can peruse to find this information. Thanks!

Comment: You can try looking it up on the compatibility reports - http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity/softwareReqsForProduct.html

Comment: Thanks Paul - will check it.